# How does value of (String... args) affect in subclass overriding?

Tags: java, overriding

if a class Alpha has a method with arguments as `public void foo(String... args)` & same method is tried to be overridden in a sub-class Beta by say `public void foo(String a)`.And a reference object is created & instantiated to subclass Beta &  trying to access  foo method from Alpha. Its returning the value from Alpha class instead of the value from Beta Sub-class .

Shouldnt it return the value from BETA class as its initialized & assigned Beta class Object ?

What is the difference b/w `Method(String ... args)` & `Method(String a)`?

Comment: And read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: Why would you think that `foo(String...)` can be overridden with `foo(String)`?

Comment: String... is array of parameters, not only a single string

Answer (score 2):

It's because the method in `Beta` does **not** override the one in Alpha because it does not have the same formal parameters. `String...` is not the same as `String`, much like the way `String[]` is not the same as `String`.

Comment: should parameters also be same, my understanding was overriding is on basis of method name & not on parameters .

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html. Yes the parameters should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

A method with 1 parameter of `String` does *not* override a method with 1 parameter of `String...`.  The parameter type `String...` is a variable arity method, meaning 0 or more arguments can be passed, e.g. `foo("one", "two", "three")`.  In the body of the method, it is treated as an array, not a single `String`.  If you had used `@Override` in `Beta`'s declaration of `foo`, the compiler would catch that you didn't override `foo`.  You have overloaded `foo` instead.

To override a method, you must have the parameters and the name of the method match exactly.  In fact, you can't even have the type be `String[]`, even if the parameters are both treated as arrays, due to how the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

**Method overriding** occurs when a subclass tries to implement a method with:

- same method signature as the method in the parent class

**Method overloading** occurs when more than 1 method uses the same method name but having different method signature. *(Method overloading can occur within the same class, i.e. no sub-classing needed)*

**Method signature includes**:

- Method name
- Method parameter list

**Excludes**

- Method return type
- Access modifiers (public/protected/private)
- Other modifiers (final/static/etc..)

---

**PROOF**

You can actually easily test what you asked by yourself:

```
class Parent{
    public void doWork(String s1, String s2){
        System.out.println("From Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    @Override   //<-This will tell you whether it successfully overridden or not
    public void doWork(String s1){
        System.out.println("From Child");
    }
}
```

**The Output?**

It will be an error. Because you are telling the ***Child*** class to override method `doWork(String)` from Parent. However such method cannot be found in the Parent class. The ***Parent*** class only has a method known as `doWork(String, String)`.

**Conclusion:**
Answer to you question is no, it will ***not be overridden*** since the method from the child class is having a different method signature with the parent class' method.

Comment: @suni If you have already cleared your doubts, you can accept one of the solutons here by clicking at the hollow tick beside the answer. You get 2 rep in return.